# Background tasks in JavaScript that do not interfere UI interaction

Tags: javascript, background, dom-events, web-worker

I am working on a mobile App implemented in JavaScript that has to do lots of background stuff -- mainly fetching data from a server (via JSONP) and writing it into a database using local storage. In the foreground the user may navigate on the locally stored data and thus wants a smoothly reacting App.

This interaction (fetching data from server via JSONP and after doing some minor work with it, storing it in the local database) is done asynchronously, but because of the necessary DOM manipulation for JSONP and the database interaction I am not able to this work with WebWorkers. Thus I am running in the problem in blocking the JavaScript event queue with lots of "background processing requests" and the App reacts very slowly (or even locks completely).

Here is a small sketch of the way I am doing the background stuff:

```
    var pendingTasksOnNewObjects = new Object();
    
    //add callbacks to queue
    function addTaskToQueue(id, callback) {
        if (!pendingTasksOnNewObjects[id]) {
            pendingTasksOnNewObjects[id] = new Array();
        }
        pendingTasksOnNewObjects[id].push(callback);
    }
    
    // example for this pending tasks:
    var myExampleTask = function () {
        this.run = function(jsonObject) {
            // do intersting stuff here as early as a specific new object arrives
            // i.e. update some elements in the DOM to respect the newly arrived object
        };
    };
    addTaskToQueue("id12345", myExampleTask);
    
    // method to fetch documents from the server via JSONP
    function getDocuments(idsAsCommaSeparatedString) {
        var elem;
        elem = document.createElement("script");
        elem.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        elem.setAttribute("src", "http://serverurl/servlet/myServlet/documents/"+idsAsCommaSeparatedString);
        document.head.appendChild(elem);
    }
    
    // "callback" method that is used in the JSONP result to process the data
    function locallyStoreDocuments(jsonArray) {
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<jsonArray.length; i++) {
            var obj = jsonArray[i];
            storeObjectInDatabase(obj);
            runTasks(obj.docID, obj);
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    // process tasks when new object arrives
    function runTasks(id, jsonObject) {
        if(pendingTasksOnNewObjects[id]) {
            while(pendingTasksOnNewObjects[id][0]) {
                pendingTasksOnNewObjects[id][0].run(jsonObject);
                pendingTasksOnNewObjects[id].shift();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I already looked around reading some stuff about the event processing mechanisms in JavaScript (i.e. [John Resigs description of working with timers](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)), but what I really want to do is the following: Check if there is something to do in the event queue. If so, wait for 100ms and check again. If nothing is currently waiting in the queue, process a small amount of data and check again.

As far as I read, this is not possible, since JavaScript does not have direct access to the event queue.

So are there any design ideas on how to optimize my code to get closer to the goal not to interfere with the UI events to give the user a smooth App interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Web Workers seem to be available in iOS 5, http://caniuse.com/webworkers

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as I stated above, Web Workers are not applicable since I have to do DOM manipulation to request the JSONP data and local storage to process the results. Both are not available in Web Workers.